# Doubt indentation in align environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, align, line-breaking, ampersand

Is there a way to do the following?

```
\begin{align*}
a&=b +c +d\\
&=c
\end{align*}
```

The problem is `b+c+d` is an extremely long equation so I want to linebreak after `d` and I want to put on the next line so that it nicely aligns with `c`, so I want it to look like

```
a=b+c
   +d
 =e
```

How do you do this?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to achieve this. Here are two options, one using `\phantom`s and another using multiple alignment points via `alignat`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  a &= b + c + d \\
    &= c
\end{align*}

% Option 1
\begin{align*}
  a &= b + c \\
    &\phantom{{}= b} + d \\
    &= c
\end{align*}

% Option 2
\begin{alignat*}{2}
  a &= b &&+ c \\
    &    &&+ d \\
    &= c
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use a nested `aligned`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  a &= \begin{aligned}[t] 
         b &+ c \\
           &+ d
       \end{aligned}\\
    &= c
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]